# How do I get my game to recognise this public function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is within tile.as

No traces in this function run. 
There is also a public function tile as the constructor.

```
 public function start():void
    {
     trace("workingwell");
        if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }
    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("starting");
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

Above it:

```
import main;
import boxsprite;
import StatusBox;
import Set;
```

also a main.as on the main command line- that runs.

Comment: Add the constructor body please

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need the private functions called  from this public function to call the constructor- public function tile(i:uint,kana1:String,value1:uint, type1:uint):void
 
 
 {
  id = i;
   kana = kana1;
   value = value1;
   type = type1;
   currentmultipliers = multiplier;
      go(); // this function will be called when you create a new tile object
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that 'trace' is on the first line of the start function, I'd say the start function isn't getting called. The Tile constructor will run 'automatically' when you instantiate a new Tile, but if you're not calling start from SOMEwhere, then obviously the function won't run and the trace won't happen.

Comment: Main.as does not recognise start() gives a error- should be imported with import tile; As3 is so rubbish.

Comment: It can seem like AS3 doesn't make sense as you're learning, but rest assured, it will be something that you don't understand that is causing the problem. Frustrating but true. That said, I'm not sure I understand your comment. If your Tile Class is in the same folder as your .fla file you shouldn't have to import it. You WILL have to call the start function on an instance of the Tile Class (eg _tile.start()) to have that function run. It won't run automatically.

Comment: Reading your comment again, it seems like you expect Main.as to have access to the start function because it's importing Tile. This is not the case. You will need to create an instance of Tile and store that instance in a variable (eg var _tile:Tile = new Tile()). You will then be able to access the functions defined in that instance (eg _tile.start()).

Answer (score 0):

Call start() function in your Constructor or in your go() function